# Game-Rig-Tools error when loading animations to bake

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on, baking, error

I updated to blender 3.1, added rigify and game-rig-tools, regenerated my rig and did some changes in my animations(position of keyframes). Then i wanted to bake my animations onto my Game_Rig that i created, but when i try to load animations from my Control_Rig i get this error message. I see that theres float type number somewhere where an int should be, but i have no idea what is causing that. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this problem would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: It's a known issue, they're working on it: if you want to use Game-rig-tools stay on 3.0 version, until it gtes fixed.

Comment: Many thanks, never thought it was blender 3.1 issue, i thought i missed some setting or something.